# Why is $\sin(4\pi/5)$ equal to $\sin(\pi/5)$

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I am trying to understand why $$\sin(4\pi/5) = \sin(\pi/5)$$
Is there any formula that could help me? Thank you

Comment: $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi/4 + x)$, then why isn't $x=x+\pi/4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352772/if-sinx-sin-pi-4-x-then-why-isnt-x-x-pi-4)

Comment: Type `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, `$\cot x$` to obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$, respectively.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the identity $\sin(\pi-x) = \sin x$, we have,

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{5}) = \sin(\pi - \frac{\pi}{5})= \sin\frac{4\pi}{5}$

Comment: Type `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, `$\cot x$` to obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$, respectively.